# How to exclude points beyond a line in R

Tags: r, dataframe, spatial

I'm working with two dataframes in R: a "red" dataframe and a "black" dataframe. In both there are two columns representing the coordinates.
I used a plot to explain what I want to do.

I would like to select all the points from the "red" dataframe that are beyond the "black" line. E.g. all the points excluded from the area of the polygon delimited by the black points.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer only showed how not to *draw* the points outside the polygon. To actually *identify* the points outside the polygon, you can use the function [`pip2d`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ptinpoly/versions/2.8/topics/pip2d) from the package `ptinpoly`. It returns negative values for points outside the polygon.

Example:

```
library(ptinpoly)
poly.vertices <- data.frame(x=c(20,40,80,50,40,30), y=c(30,20,70,80,50,60))
p <- data.frame(x=runif(100, min=0, max=100), y=runif(100, min=0, max=100))

outside <- (pip2d(as.matrix(poly.vertices), as.matrix(p)) < 0)

plot(p$x, p$y, col=ifelse(outside, "red", "black"))
polygon(poly.vertices$x, poly.vertices$y, border="blue", col=NA)
```

The same should be achieved with the function [`PtInPoly`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.45/topics/PtInPoly) from the package `DescTools`, which returns zero for points outside the polygon. The implementation of `ptinpoly`, however, has the advantage of implmenting the particularly efficient algorithm described in

> J. Liu, Y.Q. Chen, J.M. Maisog, G. Luta: "A new point containment test algorithm based on preprocessing and determining triangles." Computer-Aided Design, Volume 42, Issue 12, December 2010, Pages 1143-1150

**Edit:** Out of curiosity, I have compared the runtime of `ptinpoly::pip2d` and `DescTools::PtInPoly` with microbenchmark and `N=50000` points, and `pip2d` turned out to be considerably faster:

```
> microbenchmark(outside.pip2d(), outside.PtInPoly())
Unit: milliseconds
              expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq      max
   outside.pip2d()  3.375084  3.421631  4.459051  3.48939  4.251395 65.97793
outside.PtInPoly() 27.537927 27.666688 28.739288 27.97984 28.514595 90.11313
```

neval
100
100

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution! I tried but it seems that is quite computationally challenging. I think I need a solution based on dataframe joining or filtering

Comment: Have you tried both `DescTools::PtInPoly` and `ptinpoly::pip2d` and both are too slow? As a preprocessig step, you can remove all points that are obviously outside (all points outside the outer bounding box of the polygon) and obviously inside (all points inside the largest rectangle inside the polygon), but this might still leave over too many points.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `sf` package to define a convex hull and intersect your target points with that polygon.

Define a convex hull based on `black`:

```
library(sf)

set.seed(99)
red <- data.frame(x = runif(100,-10,10), y = runif(100,-4,4))
black <- data.frame(x = runif(100,-8,8), y = runif(100,-4,3))

# Convert df to point feature
blk <- st_as_sf(black, coords = c("x", "y"))
# Convert to multipoint
blk_mp <- st_combine(blk)
# Define convex hull
blk_poly <- st_convex_hull(blk_mp)

plot(black)
points(red, col = "red")
plot(blk_poly, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Intersecting `red` with the convex hull returns `red` within that polygon:

```
rd <- st_as_sf(red, coords = c("x", "y"))
rd_inside <- st_intersection(rd, blk_poly)

plot(black)
points(red)
plot(blk_poly, add = TRUE)
plot(rd_inside, pch = 24, col = "red", bg = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: The "black line" corresponds to a concave polygon.

Comment: I think using the convex hull suggested by @Skaqqs could be the right way, the problem is that I need to draw a line that traces the contour as precisely as possible. Indeed a convex hull doesn't work for me because I will include in the convex all the red points in the diagonal that would be formed in the upper left-hand corner of the plot, not being able to exclude them and retrieve them

Comment: @Giordano, Can you share the data you used to make the plot in your question? If you points are in order, we could easily convert them to a polygon.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to draw the polygon after the points and fill its outer area white. This cannot be done directly with `polygon` or `polypath`, because these functions can only fill the interiour of a polygon. You can however fill the area *between* two polygons with `polypath`. Thus you can add a second polygon that encompasses (or goes beyond) the borders of your plot.

Here is an example that works in base R:

```
p.outer <- list(x=c(0,100,100,0), y=c(0,0,100,100))
p.inner <- list(x=c(20,40,80,50,40,30), y=c(30,20,70,80,50,60))
plot(p.outer, type="n")
points(runif(100, min=0, max=100), runif(100, min=0, max=100))
polypath(x=c(p.outer$x, NA, p.inner$x), y = c(p.outer$y, NA, p.inner$y), col ="white", rule="evenodd")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the function PtInPoly of package DescTools, as suggested by @cdalitz, I resolved the problem. This function returned a data frame of the coordinates of the points (in my case the red coordinates) and a third column "pip" of 1 (if the point is within the polygon) and 0s (if outside the polygon).

I will use another dataset to show you the result:

```
 try <- DescTools::PtInPoly(pnts = red[,c("x","y")], poly.pnts = black[,c("x","y")])

 ggplot()+
      geom_point(try, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.character(pip))) +
      geom_polygon(data = black, mapping = aes(x,y))
```

[image]

Comment: As you commented above that `ptinpoly::pip2d` was too slow for your needs, I wonder why `DescTools::PtInPoly` was faster. In my tests, it was the other way around.

Comment: I don't know actually. Using ptinpoly my R crashed. I thought it was for computational effort

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can reconstruct the edges of the black polygon by simply joining every point to its nearest neighbor and its nearest neighbor in the opposite direction. Then perform point-in-polygon tests.

Comment: Seems an interesting idea, do you know how to do it in R?

Comment: @Giordano: I don't, sorry :-)

Comment: @giordano, perhaps you could translate this to R? I could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846431/ordering-shuffled-points-that-can-be-joined-to-form-a-polygon-in-python

Comment: @Skaqqs: this method is not the same and will not work here.